# How To show animation of a pie chart after scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, pie-chart

I make a pie chart using Easy pie chart. For reveal when scroll I use Wow.js . But I want to show the pie chart increasing to its define percentage when scroll.Its show me if I am on that part. But I want to show this animation after scroll.How can I do this. Please help me.

Here is the code for easy pie chart I use

```
$('.chart').easyPieChart({
    'barColor':'#AD984E',
    'scaleColor':'#141414',
    'trackColor':'#EEEEEE',
    'size':'200',
    'lineWidth':'5',
    animate: 5000
});
```

and for wow js

```
 wow = new WOW(
    {
      boxClass:     'wow',      // default
      animateClass: 'animated', // default
      offset:       100,          // default
      mobile:       true,       // default
      live:         true        // default
    }
  )
  wow.init();
```

This is the link of my work: http://kapilpaul.uphero.com/autoputzer/

TIA

Comment: ok, you should make the pie chart "display none" and wisible them on scroll position. it will work

Comment: okay let me check that.

Comment: how to do with that.using window scroll function in jQuery?? or any other way

Comment: if you animate pie chart than used instead of easyPieChart you should used highchartJs javascript library. highchartJs have lots more animation function than easyPieChart.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this code:**

```
    $(window).scroll( function(){

    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.chart').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it in */
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

        $('.chart').easyPieChart({
          size: 140,
          lineWidth: 6,
          lineCap: "square",
          barColor: "#22a7f0",
          trackColor: "#ffffff",
          scaleColor: !1,
          easing: 'easeOutBounce',
          animate: 5000,
          onStep: function(from, to, percent) {
          $(this.el).find('.percent').text(Math.round(percent));
          }
        });

        }

    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put this code in your main js file after including the easyPieChart.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function(){
    var postionTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    console.log(postionTop);
    if((postionTop >=600)){
        $('.chart').easyPieChart({
            animate: 2000,
       });
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: Please provide some explanations along with your code, so that future users can follow your ideas/code more easily. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23349369)

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code

You can use the data attribute to handle the animation speed of each chart

```
<div class="chart" data-speed="5000"></div>
```

JavaScript Code

```
$(window).scroll( function(){

    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.chart').each( function(i){
var el = $(this),
speed = el.data('speed');

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it in */
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

        $(this).easyPieChart({
          size: 140,
          lineWidth: 6,
          lineCap: "square",
          barColor: "#22a7f0",
          trackColor: "#ffffff",
          scaleColor: !1,
          easing: 'easeOutBounce',
          animate: speed ,
          onStep: function(from, to, percent) {
          $(this.el).find('.percent').text(Math.round(percent));
          }
        });

        }

    }); 

});
```